# Absolutely positioned elements with scrolling containers

Tags: html, css

An absolute positioned element is supposed to be removed from the element flow, and (so I understand) not able to make the document larger (creating scrollbars) but just go out of sight and out of mind.

But in my experiment when I offset an absolute element to the left I get scrollbars and to the right I get the expected behaviour. Why does it do this, and how could I get the behaviour I was expecting?

http://jsbin.com/bosajigapifu/6/edit

Comment: If you put the positioned absolute element into a container that is `width:100%` , but `overflow: hidden` you can "push it into the void" that way. As long as its container does not go outside of the realm of the window it will not show scroll bars.

Comment: @CayceK This seems to be a very elegant solution, I thought it only hid the scrollbars but it does exactly what I hoped. If you make this into an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: thanks for that! I did as you asked and added the elements how they should look and style JUST IN CASE someone has a question it should cover it. That and I didn't want to just copy my comment 100%.. seemed lazy to me. Glad you got it worked out though! Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put the positioned absolute element into a container that is `width: 100%`, but `overflow: hidden` you can "push it into the void" that way. As long as its container does not go outside of the realm of the window it will not show scroll bars.

Elements:

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="absolute"></div>
</div>
```

Styles:

```
<style>
  #container{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #absolute{
    position: absolute;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely positioned elements don't push other *elements*, but it does push out scroll-boxes if the element it's positioned relative to is the nearest scrolling ancestor.

The idea is that it's content and should be displayed. Kind of annoying tho when you want to position something outside a scroll container.

Comment: So what should I do when I want to animate something out of the container into the void?

Comment: @Tim You could use `transform`'s `translateX()`.

Comment: Don't put it in a positioned (position: absolute or position: relative) container.  If you remove the relative position of the parent, the absolute element will be positioned with respect to the document and can magically disappear from the screen.

Comment: @post_erasmus Like this: http://jsbin.com/noqogahekuba/2/edit ? Because there is no change in behaviour

Answer (score 1):

You may use `position: fixed` instead of absolute.

The diference is that it is not subject to any parent element, only to the viewport itself, but it does not create scrollbars when offset...

http://jsfiddle.net/t6g4421a/

Comment: But it does if you go to the right side of the screen. I don't think this is what he is shooting for. I think he wants to be able to go both ways.

Comment: Even to the right, it does not create scrollbars... http://jsfiddle.net/t6g4421a/

Comment: you are correct. That is my bad. I was testing something that was out of scope of the ability and didn't notice. Thank you for getting me on the right track!